# The point on the curve $y = 2 \sqrt{x}$ that is closest to the point $(2,0)$

Tags: calculus

Calculate the coordinates of the point on the curve $y = 2 \sqrt{x}$ that is closest to the point $(2,0)$.

What I did was I found the slope. Then I set the slope equal to the derivative. From then on, I don't know what to do. I came to a dead end.

Comment: Is that exactly how the problem is written?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I have two suggestions: 1. Learn to use your shift key. 2. Explain what you mean about finding the slope (of what?) and "setting" the slope (of what?).

Comment: @Amzoti, Now it is. Forgot to type a word in, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The distance function can be written as

$$d(x) = (x-2)^2+4 x = x^2+4$$

Where is this a minimum?

Comment: Wow, I didnt learn that.

Comment: This is kind of a special case, where the distance turns out to have a peculiarly simple form.

Answer (score 0):

In analytic geometry, the distance between two points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ of the $xy$-plane can be found using the distance formula as follows (obtained by the Pythagorean Theorem):

$$ \sigma = \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2}.$$

Thus,

$$ \sigma = \sqrt{(x-2)^2 + (y-0)^2} = \sqrt{(x-2)^2 + (2\sqrt{x}-0)^2} = \sqrt{x^2 +4}.$$

Now, you need to find out for what value of $x$, $\sigma$ is minimum. In order to achieve that, you need to take the first derivative of $\sigma$ and equate the expression to zero (finding critical points). The solution for the obtained equation is the answer to your question. Hence,

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sigma = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+4}} = 0 $$

which has a unique answer $x=0$.

Therefore, $(0,2\sqrt{0}) = (0,0)$ is the closest point on the curve to the point $(2,0)$.